# Can't import shapefile to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import

I am using postgresql 9.4.1 and postgis 2.1(pg 94) and also qgis 2.4.0. All the installation went well. But, when I tried to import shapefile to postgis via postgis shp & dbf loader it couldn't work! Here is the warning message:

> ==============================
>
> Importing with configuration: area, public, geom, D:\temp\area.shp,
>   mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
>   Shapefile type: Arc PostGIS type: MULTILINESTRING[2] Failed SQL
>   begins: "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8; SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS
>   TO ON; BEGIN; CREATE TABLE "public"."area" (gid serial, "objectid"
>   int4, "fid_block3" int4, "shape_leng" numeric); ALTER TABLE
>   "public"."area" ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid); SELECT AddGeometryColumn('pu"
>   Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  fungsi addgeometrycolumn(unknown,
>   unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) tidak ada LINE 9: SELECT
>   AddGeometryColumn('public','area','geom','0','MULTILI...
>                  ^
>
> HINT:  Tidak ada fungsi yang sesuai dengan nama dan tipe argumen yang
>   diberikan.Anda mungkin perlu menambakan cast tipe eksplisit
>
> Shapefile import failed.
>
> ==============================

At first I thought it was because of my shapefile is broken. But it was not. I try to produce new shapefile and still couldn't import!
If anyone ever found the same case, please share your solution to me.

Oh ya, in addition, I also have tried the SPIT tools in qgis and still I can't import the shapefile with warning massage:

Problem inserting features from file:
D:/temp/for_postgres/poligon.shp

Error while executing the SQL:

> SELECT f_table_name FROM geometry_columns WHERE
>   f_table_name='poligon' AND  f_table_schema='public'
>
> The database
>   said:ERROR:  relasi Â«  geometry_columns Â» sudah ada LINE 1: SELECT
>   f_table_name FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name...^

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really understand the hint.

Comment: Hi Micky, the hint said this in english :  
There is no function that matches the name and type of arguments given. You may need to add explicit type cast. << Thats it. Hope you could give me suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Seems there is something wrong in you shapefile definition or in the syntax used to load it. could you try with "shp2pgsql-gui" interface?

Comment: Hi Micky, thank you for your suggestion. Ya, I've just tried "shp2pgsql-gui" interface but the warning message appear again with the same comment. I will try to unistall the postgis and reinstall. Maybe it can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. take a look at [this](http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Unable-to-import-shapefile-using-Shapefile-to-PostGIS-Importer-td4992098.html).

Comment: I did it, even reinstall all package (postgre & postgis). Actually I've just realise that, my spatial database (which I created during postgis installation) is not appear in my database. Only default database which appear (postgres). There is no change even I reinstall the software. I totally have no idea about this case...

Comment: Have you created the database from the PostGIS template? Does the functions in this database include all the PostGIS functions?

Comment: If you are on ubuntu-like OS [here](http://www.michelebeneventi.it/installare-postgis-2-x-come-estensione-su-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) you are an example of installation, but I think that we're going OT.

Comment: Hi Tengshe, actually in my postgis installation, I also created the spatial database. But when finish, I don't know why the postgis template is not appear in my database (it only appear the default postgress).

Comment: Hi Micky, I am using windows 7, but thank for the link...

Comment: you can use the syntax on windows as well.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you have to configure postGIS library as extension in your database. [Here](http://www.michelebeneventi.it/installare-postgis-2-x-come-estensione-su-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) an example.

Comment: Hi Micky, thank you in advance for your help. Yes I've tried to enable the extension by your tutorial. It works! I do not have problem to import shapefile now. Many thanks :)